# Updating UI elements bound to T after ObservableCollection<T>.Clear() is invoked

Tags: wpf

Stack,

I am prototyping a registration form in WPF. The user specifies their beer preference. Beer is a `enum`.

The `PersonModel` has `ObservableCollection<Beer>` called `BeerPreferences`.

The `PersonViewModel` re-projects `BeerPreferences` for checkbox binding in the `PersonView`. For example their is: `IsLaggerPreferred`, `IsPaleAlePreferred`, and `IsIPAPreferred`. Their implementations each check, add, remove the `Beer` enum from the `BeerPreferences` collection.

I want to add the `bool` property `HasNoPreference` to `PersonViewModel` that when set to `true`, will clear any previously made selections. The `HasNoPreference` getter calls BeerPreferences.Clear().

How do I notify the `PersonView` to update the checkboxes bound to `IsLaggerPreferred`, `IsPaleAlePreferred`, and `IsIPAPreferred` when `HasNoPreference` is checked?

Fundamentally, `HasNoPreference` triggers an indirect transient action. How do you trigger the unsuspecting UI elements to refresh?

One approach would be to change from using Beer enums to a class which implements INPC. I like the simplicity of just using the Beer enum. Are there any other approachs I am overlooking?

Comment: A bit of code is for sure better than this long cumbersome story.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `PropertyChanged("IsLaggerPreferred")`, `PropertyChanged("IsPaleAlePreferred")`, `PropertyChanged("IsIPAPreferred")` from the `HasNoPreference` setter. Or you may `PropertyChanged("")` to update every single UI control bound to the view model.